# TimerTask, Ayuda (modificado)

Tags: java

Inicio el método al iniciar el programa, lo que necesito es que se ejecute el bucle y después genere un tiempo de espera (1 minuto) y vuelva a ejecutar la tarea pasado el tiempo de espera(pero que también ejecute el bucle.. y así sucesivamente) 
Conforme lo tengo ahora, al entrar al método lanza el tiempo de espera.

```
   public void comprobarFallos() {
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaFallos.size(); i++) {
            if (listaFallos.get(i).equals("1")) {
                playAudios.playAudio(listaAudios.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
};
// Aquí se pone en marcha el timer CADA 2 MINUTOs
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, TIEMPOESPERA);}
```

Comment: que tarea se tiene que lanzar?

Comment: Comprueba los errores activos, y reproduce un audio

Comment: @R.Priego te refieres al bucle que se encuentra dentro de run() ?

Answer (score 0):

El trozo de codigo que colocaste está correcto hasta donde yo lo veo.
al ejecutar el método `comprobarFallos()` se setea el timer a 2 minutos para ejecutar la timerTask, y luego retorna el método. De manera síncrona el timer corre por detrás hasta que ocurre la señal del timer y ejecuta el método `run`

Creo que tu pregunta el falta especificación en cuanto a lo que deseas que ocurra, y falta contexto como para que sepamos donde puede estar el error.
Si dices que al ejecutar el programa se está seteando el timer automaticamente sin llamar a `comprobarFallos()`. Entonces probablemente haya un error en otra parte del codigo, posiblemente estas llamando al método en otra parte. Como no puedo ver el resto del codigo no sabría decirte con seguridad; hasta donde veo está correcto.

Por favor explica más a que te refieres con realizar la comprobación (bucle), que bucle te refieres?

Ojala te sirva de algo mi respuesta. De todas maneras si agregas más información a tu pregunta, editaré mi respuesta para intentar ayudarte más; pero con la poca información que diste es dificil hacer más.

Answer (score 0):

Al finalizar el  bucle, declara tu `TimerTask`, iniciara la primera ocasión inmediatamente y posteriormente lo definido en `TIEMPOESPERA`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listaFallos.size(); i++) {
                if (listaFallos.get(i).equals("1")) {
                    playAudios.playAudio(listaAudios.get(i));
                }
  }

  //al finalizar el bucle creas TimerTask

     timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //Realiza tarea!...
        }
    };
    // Aquí se pone en marcha el timer CADA 2 MINUTOs
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, TIEMPOESPERA);
```